# print_control_identifiers | UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ue72b' in position 21: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: pywinauto

The print_control_identifiers giving ERROR:  UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ue72b' in position 21: character maps to

```
    mainContent.print_control_identifiers(filename="mainContent.txt")
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 696, in print_control_identifiers
    print_identifiers([this_ctrl, ], log_func=log_func)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 685, in print_identifiers
    print_identifiers(ctrl.children(), current_depth + 1, log_func)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 681, in print_identifiers
    log_func(output)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 694, in log_func
    log_file.write(str(msg) + os.linesep)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\codecs.py", line 721, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\codecs.py", line 377, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ue72b' in position 21: character maps to <undefined>
```

I do not see how to make it `UTF8` or make it as `errors='ignore'`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to the top of your .py file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```